# libpng error: Read Error when reading many files from dir

Tags: python, opencv, libpng

I'm using:

python 3.5

cv2 4.4.0

libpng 1.6.34

I tried leading multiple .png files from a directory using:

`img_seq = [cv2.imread(img) for img in glob.glob('*.png')]`

However this gives an error:

`libpng error: Read Error`

I tried:

- updating libpng - didn't work
- loading only a part of the files, and it works up until 164 files:

   `img_seq = [cv2.imread(img) for img in glob.glob('*.png')[:163]]`

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, I think I need a little more explanation about the error situation. Didn't you get an error when using it with matplotlib or latex? Are you sure there is no problem with the 164th image itself? You should also check the file read permission.

It would be nice to resolve the error, but if you are sure that there is no problem, it would be better to wrap it with a try-except statement.

```
for img in glob.glob('*.png'):
    try:
        cv2.imread(img)
    except:
        pass
```